# Javascript - Fazendo divisão dentro de um array

Tags: javascript, array, funções

Estou tentando resolver um exercício, e estou com dificuldades para saber onde estou errando, alguma dica?

Exercício :

Programe uma função `buscarDivisivelPor` que recebe dois parâmetros, um `array` de números e um número de teste, retornando como resposta o primeiro número do `array` que seja divisível pelo número dado e diferente de zero. Caso nenhum número do `array` passe no teste, retorne o texto "Nenhum número válido encontrado!".

Meu código :

```
function buscarDivisivelPor(array, num) {
  for ( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if( (array[i] % num ) && (!0) ){
      console.log(array[i])
      break
    } else {
      console.log("Nenhum número válido encontrado!")
    }
  }    
}


//Exemplo de array : [0, 9, 4, 7, 128, 42, -1, 301, -5]  num : 2 
//A resposta deveria ser 4
```

Comment: qual o problema? se não relatou o que está acontecendo

Comment: Estou tentando passar um array no parametro array, e um numero aleatorio no parametro num para realizar a conta. Porém não está retornando como devia. @VirgilioNovic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, tente usar esse código e se atente aos meus comentários! Bons estudos!

```
function buscarDivisivelPor(array, num) {
      
      for(var i=0; i<=array.length;i++){
         
         if (array[i] % num == 0 && array[i] != 0) { /* resto zero e valor do array tem que ser diferente de 0*/
            
             return array[i]; /* não dá para retornar um contador, então a contagem vai parar no primeiro valor que atenda a condição*/
          } 
             
       } 
       return "Nenhum número válido encontrado!"; /* O return precisa ser fora da condição e do loop porque dessa forma a frase será impressa só uma vez, isto é, quando o array inteiro não atender os requisitos*/
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

O seu problema está na condicional, o desafio pede para você printar o número divisível, para você saber se um número é divisível por 2 é necessário verificar se o resto é zero.

**No código**:

```
if (array[i] % num === 0) {

}
```

É necessário que o número seja **diferente de zero**, para verificar essa condição, você usou
`if (!0) {}` e essa condicional **sempre será verdadeira**, visto que 0 é considerado falso.

O que você precisa é verificar se o número é diferente de zero.

***No código***:

```
if (array[i] !== 0) {

}
```

**O seu código ficaria assim:**

```
function buscarDivisivelPor(array, num) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if((array[i] % num === 0) && (array[i] !== 0) ){
      console.log(array[i]);
    
      break
    }
  }    
}
```

**Solucionando o desafio:**

```js
function searchFirstNumberDivisibleBy(divider, numbers = []) {
    const firstNumberFound = numbers.find(
      number => number % divider === 0 && number !== 0,
    );

    if (!firstNumberFound) {
      throw new Error('Nenhum número válido encontrado!');
    }

    return firstNumberFound;
}
```

Comment: agradeço a explicação, porém após fazer as modificações continuo a receber as seguintes mensagens de erro : Para o array [0, 9, 4, 7, 128, 42, -1, 301, -5] e num = 2 a reposta deve ser 4
Para o array [0, 9, 4, 7, 128, 42, -1, 301, -5] e num = 7 a reposta deve ser 7
Para o array [0, 9, 4, 7, 128, 42, -1, 301, -5] e num = 8 a reposta deve ser 128
Para o array [0, 9, 4, 7, 128, 42, -1, 301, -5] e num = 8 a reposta deve ser 128
Para o array [0, 9, 4, 7, 128, 42, -1, 301, -5] e num = 100 a reposta deve ser uma mensagem de erro . Acredito que o algoritmo de correção não esteja aceitando.

Comment: Você está correto, eu não implementei o seu desafio. Eu consertei onde estava errado e te mostrei o porque estava ocorrendo as inconsistências...

O que você precisa tentar fazer agora é exibir a mensagem de erro quando não achar um número.

Comment: Editei o post com uma solução.